# submiting form form webrowser with qrscanner in windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code, keypress

i'm developing simple app control which starting an specific website from localhost in client net. the idea is that he will control all website with qrscanner by reading specific qrcodes.

I tried to listen specific PreviewKeyDown Events but it's only reading one keypress.

What is the best way to "listen" keypresses in this case?

I want that, if user whenever he will be ( but not in 2 input forms which providing order code and user code - also from qr code - when he use qr code and read code like: " #cmd#001 " it will run for example messagebox - you've done it ( in final version form will be sended )